# equals() method not working

Tags: java, equals

The `equals()` method should check if the dimensions of the first box and the cube are the same. How to fix it? It currently does not work.

The program returns the message `"illegal start of type"` at if. I am new to this plz help

```
public class testNew
{

 public static void main (String []args)
 {
  Rectangle3 one = new Rectangle3(5,20);
  Box3 two = new Box3(4,4,4);
  Box3 three = new Box3(4,10,5);
  Cube3 four = new Cube3(4,4,4);

  showEffectBoth(one);
  showEffectBoth(two);
  showEffectBoth(three);
  showEffectBoth(four);
 }

  public static String showEffectBoth(Rectangle3 r)
 {
  return System.out.println(r);
 }

 boolean b = two.equals(four);

if (b == true)
{
 System.out.println("Box and cube have the same dimensions");
}


}


public class Rectangle3
{
// instance variables 
int length;
int width;

public Rectangle3(int l, int w)
{
 length = l;
 width = w;
}

public int getLength()
{
  return length;
}
public int getWidth()
{
  return width;
}
public String toString()
{
   return getClass().getName() + " - " + length + " X " + width;
}
public boolean equals(Rectangle3 obj) 
{
    if ((getLength().equals(obj.getLength()) && getWidth().equals(obj.getWidth())))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    }

  }
```

Comment: `if (b == true)` is not within a method. It needs to be. That is the cause of your error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First**, regarding the compiler error you have, it has nothing to do with the  `equals()` method. It's only because all of the code below, should be inside your main method as it's the only part where you are declaring the variables`two` and `four`:

```
boolean b = two.equals(four);

   if (b == true) {
        System.out.println("Box and cube have the same dimensions");
   }
```

Notice also, that the `Rectangle3` class shouldn't be in the same file as `testNew` as both are declared `public`, if you want to use both of them in the same file then you need to remove the `public` declration from one of them (the one you will not use as filename)

**Second**, your `equals()` method is technically correct (I guess functionally as well) but it's not the `equals()` method you included in your code here, because this one belong to `Rectangle3` while the `equals()` you are testing here should be defined in `Box3` and `Cube3`

**NB:** Please notice as per assylias's comment, that because `b` is a `boolean` there is no need to use `if (b == true)`, just `if (b)` will be sufficient

Comment: @assylias Yes absolutely, I tried to correct the code but didn't paid attention to that! I will update as an NB, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not the equals function. The line

```
boolean b = two.equals(four)
```

Is illegal. It is not within any method and it references variables declared in main()!